# How to prevent the 'Save (image) as' dialog on Ctrl+click in Opera

Tags: javascript, browser, selection, opera

I have to create an image gallery where user can select some images and then process them. The selection should be done via Ctrl+LeftClick of the mouse. It works well in FF and IE8, but when I Ctrl+click in Opera, new dialog "Save as" appears which causes saving the clicked image.

How do I prevent opening the dialog in Opera? (it's probably system setting)
I haven't still found any solution. The question at [Opera](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=240344)  remains unanswered since June,2008 :(

Is it even possible? Ctrl+Click is standard way in OS, that's probably the problem - adapting desktop behaviour to web.

Comment: I agree this should be possible and I've reported an Opera bug for this issue (reference DSK-273043).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Opera, it is possible to set this behavior in `Tools->Preferences->Content->JavaScript Options->Allow script to detect context menu events`. This is unchecked by default, which means that most users will see the browser's context menu.

This was added to prevent "context menu hijacking"; unfortunately, this limits all browser apps to the left mouse button. You could have the user `rightclick->Edit site preferences->Scripting->Allow script to detect context menu events`; this should allow your site to use this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible - I'd advise a different key mapping for Opera (or indeed all browsers)

For example, Opera has an option where the right click context menu cannot be disabled by javascript - as a protection for Opera users.

Comment: I've read about the problems with context menu and saw there are maybe some workarounds. However, I can not tell each client "if you want to use my product, change settings in your browser". Some of them may not know that there are some settings.

Comment: Absolutely. I'd advise a different key mapping, or as scunliffe suggests, modify your UI so that a click selects an object, rather than navigating. You can stop the event to prevent the link being followed.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you make it just a click?** that would toggle each picture. e.g. first click selects, then if you click it again, it deselects.

Something like this... where you can visually see what has been picked.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is not possible. After click on the preview (that could be selected) user is redirected to a new page with full image. (so the <img /> is wrapped in <a />).

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to prevent people from saving image it is pointless. All the user needs to do to get around context-menu-hijacking is disable JavaScript temporarily on that page, or press PRINT SCREEN.

Comment: Or just go to browser cache on disk and simply copy the images. No, I only want the possibility to un/select them.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<img src="myImage.png" onclick="event.preventDefault();">
```